# How to create named pipe?

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I have this code inside of my static method:

```
PipeSecurity ps = new PipeSecurity();
ps.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, PipeAccessRights.FullControl | PipeAccessRights.CreateNewInstance, AccessControlType.Allow));

var xserver = new NamedPipeServerStream("XSocketsPipe", PipeDirection.In);
xserver.WaitForConnection();
IFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
var messageReceived = (Connection)f.Deserialize(xserver);
XSocketsData.User.Add(messageReceived);
```

Now, when I am executing my application, I am getting "Access to the path is denied." error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It normally takes *two* applications to use a named pipe.  Did you forget to mention that the *other* application dies with this exception?  And what user account it uses?  Trying to deserialize the pipe instead of the message you read from the pipe isn't going to work well either.

Answer (score 0):

NamedPipeServerStream instances must be declared bi-directional so it looks like an obfuscated M$ error message related to the constructor.

See this related question and answer:
[CallNamedPipe & NamedPipeServerStream, access denied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175317/callnamedpipe-namedpipeserverstream-access-denied)

Comment: Changing `PipeDirection` does not change anything.

Comment: Not sure if you read the link but it is the full constructor: NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("MyPipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.None). Also try running process as Administrator as it could be some permissions issue on the Windows environment. Lastly check if there is some other process using/blocking access to the resource.